# Magnetic forces

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

I can not understand the nature of magnetic forces. What is the composition of a magnetic force? If it is not composed of anything, how can it act on matter?

Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at magnetism in terms of Quantum Field theory then magnetism is one part of the electromagnetic interaction. In your question you said it wasn't composed of anything, however in QFT electromagnetism and other fundamental interactions are controlled by particles called gauge bosons.

So the electromagnetic force is caused by the gauge boson acting on the matter. And for electromagnetism the gauge boson is the photon, so photons interacting with matter is the cause of the electromagnetic force, and consequently the magnetic forces.